# How can I create (or update) a shortcut to the newest folder?

Tags: batch-file, shortcut

I want create a shortcut to a folder that is generated automatically each day after a certain operation on an Excel form. The folders name is the date, eg. 20131018. After midnight of that day, another Excel operation will creat a new folder 20131019. I need a shortcut on the desktop to this folder to update each day to reflect the new folder name, or a new shortcut created..

Comment: Please consider tu use a Windows Scheduled Task, you can create one from TaskScheduler GUI or from CLI Schtasks command.

Comment: Ok, looked at this, seems like the closest Action is Start Program, this would be where I would run the batch file that would create the shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

To get the newest directory, you can do the following in a batch file (i assume you use a rather current Windows version):

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`dir /B /A:D /O:D /T:C`) do set NewestDirectory=%%i
```

You can also add the path of the parent directory you want to search in:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`dir X:\MyParentDir /B /A:D /O:D /T:C`) do set NewestDirectory=%%i
```

The variable %NewestDirectory% will contain the name of the newest directory. 
Note, that the directory name in %NewestDirectory% will not have any quote marks, even if it contains white-spaces.

The parameter /T:C tells the dir command to use the creation date of the directories.
If more appropriate for your problem, you might use /T:W instead, which will give you the directory with the newest date of the last write access.

Shortcuts cannot be created directly in batch files. Either use a 3rd party tool, or use Windows scripting host. You might want to look at these Stack Overflow topics for further inspiration:
[Creating a shortcut for a exe using a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225880/creating-a-shortcut-for-a-exe-using-a-batch-file/2225889#2225889) 
[creating a shortcut for a exe from a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346107/creating-a-shortcut-for-a-exe-from-a-batch-file/346118#346118)

Comment: Ok thanks. The creation of the folder is already happening on the excel form I am using at work. I just want the shortcut part.  I'll check out those threads, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to create an AutoHotkey script.
- Install AutoHotkey, which is between 1MB and 10 MB to install.
- Create a file in Notepad, for example 'excel shortcut.ahk',
with the following code:

```
vToday := SubStr(A_Now, 1, 8)
vDir := "C:\My Excel Folder\" vToday
;MsgBox % vDir
;IfNotExist, % vDir
;FileCreateDir, % vDir

IfExist, % vDir
Run, % vDir
Return
```

Note: I have left some lines commented out, which could
allow you to create the folder, if it doesn't already exist,
via AutoHotkey.

Note: you could even create a shortcut to the ahk file,
if you want a literal shortcut file.